# MySQL multiple table query with average for each row

Tags: mysql

This is my setup:

- Table "files": id (PK), filename, user_id, date, filesize
- Table "scores": id(PK), file_id, user_id, score

Table "files" contains a list of files with details; table "scores" keeps track of 1-5 points scored per file. I need to get entries from the "files" table and in each row I need all the info for the file, as well as the average score. I can do another query for teh current file_id while I'm looping through the rows, but obviousely that's not very optimized. I tried something like below, but no success.

`SELECT files.*, (SUM(scores.score)/(COUNT(scores.score))) AS total FROM files INNER JOIN scores ON files.id=scores.file_id;`

Please point me in the right direction - thanks!

Comment: Why do you have `user_id` in both tables?

Comment: In "files" it indicates who this file belongs to, in "scores" it indicates who rated this file.

Comment: Consider giving the fields pertinent names then (e.g., `owner` and `rater`).

Comment: Even though <code>owner</code> and <code>rater</code> are the same type of entity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to try the following:

```
SELECT f.id, f.filename, f.user_id, f.date, f.filesize,
       (
           SELECT AVG(s.score)
           FROM   scores s
           WHERE  s.file_id = f.id
       ) average_score
FROM   files f;
```

Note that you can use the [`AVG()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) aggregate function. There is no need to divide the `SUM()` by the `COUNT()`.

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE files (id int, filename varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE scores (id int, file_id int, score int);

INSERT INTO files VALUES (1, 'f1.txt');
INSERT INTO files VALUES (2, 'f2.txt');
INSERT INTO files VALUES (3, 'f3.txt');
INSERT INTO files VALUES (4, 'f4.txt');

INSERT INTO scores VALUES (1, 1, 10);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES (2, 1, 15);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES (3, 1, 20);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES (4, 2, 5);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES (5, 2, 10);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES (6, 3, 20);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES (7, 3, 15);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES (8, 3, 15);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES (9, 4, 12);
```

Result:

```
SELECT f.id, f.filename, 
       (
           SELECT AVG(s.score)
           FROM   scores s
           WHERE  s.file_id = f.id
       ) average_score
FROM   files f;

+------+----------+---------------+
| id   | filename | average_score |
+------+----------+---------------+
|    1 | f1.txt   |       15.0000 |
|    2 | f2.txt   |        7.5000 |
|    3 | f3.txt   |       16.6667 |
|    4 | f4.txt   |       12.0000 |
+------+----------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Note that [@Ignacio's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122833/mysql-multiple-table-query-with-average-for-each-row/3122855#3122855) produces the same result, and is therefore another option.

Comment: My knowledge of SQL is sub par :( what is "scores s" and "files f"?

Comment: @Alex: The `f` in `files f` is simply an alias. This is just a shorthand for writing `f.id, f.filename` instead of `files.id, files.filename`, etc. The same applies to `scores s`.

Answer (score 3):

Aggregate functions are not usually useful without aggregation.

```
SELECT f.*, AVG(s.score) AS total
FROM files AS f
INNER JOIN scores AS s
  ON f.id=s.file_id
GROUP BY f.id
```